# Android gmail app name resolving

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to resolve the name of a contact based on an email address and display in a nifty way.
I looked in the gmail app provided, and it does a beautiful job, but I am not sure how is this implemented. (e.g http://www.habanaija.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/compose.png)
Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is done with textspans I guess they grep for mail addresses if the find well known ones e.g. from your address book it will been replaced by that nice box with an image and the real name.